# react.js how to get prop form tree element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to make table cell editable after clicking on icon in another cell , for that I need to get index of element so the editor will open in the correct row , which icon belongs to.
My issue is that I dont know the way i should get the prop value of table DOM element here is code for for clearify

**a part of dom tree generated with react:**

```
<tbody>
{stepsDone.map(function(step,idx) {

    let content = step;
    const editing = this.state.editing;

    if(editing){
        content = (
            <form onSubmit={this._save}>
              <input type="text" defaultValue={step} />
            </form>
          );
    }
    return(
            <tr key={idx}>
                <td className="step" data-step={'step'+idx}>{content}</td>
                <td className="icRow">
                        <Icon className="edit" onClick={this._showEditor} rownum={idx}/>
                        <Icon className="remove"/>
                        <Icon className="trash outline"/>
                </td>
            </tr>   
    )      
},this)}
```

**show editor function:**

```
_showEditor(e){
        this.setState({
                        editing:{
                            row:e.target.rownum
                        }
                    });
        console.log(this.state.editing);
    }
```

After execution of showedtior function console logs :
first click = *null* , which is normal i think 
more clicks = *undefined* , and thats whats brings a trouble i want to receive idx from map function.

**here is code from Icon.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

export function Icon(props) {
   const cssclasses = classNames('icon', props.className);
   return <i className={cssclasses} onClick={props.onClick}/>;
}
```

Comment: Many things... you need to bind this: "this._showEditor.bind(this)", need to use "this.state.editing" in "if(editing)". Make this changes then check some console logs.

Comment: console.log(this.state.editing); => it may not work as expected as the above this.setState is asynchronous, meaning that may not execute prior to the console.log. Try to read the event to make sure instead: console.log(e.target).

Comment: showeditor is binded , i used state in IF statment - 'const editing = this.state.editing;' , ok so now i know why its logs null after first click , but thats not real problem. console.log(e.target) its returning <i class="icon edit"> , only icon with classes but not with other props :/

Comment: ok, try moving the onClick to td instead of icon: <td className="icRow" onClick={this._showEditor} > and control the logic. Then read e.target again.

Comment: unfortunately it prints out same thing :(

Comment: someone maybe heard of **dataset ** can it solve the problem ?

Comment: it should print the e.target object. Anyway, as for the row content, I use "e.target.dataset.row"

Comment: i tried both "e.target.getAttribute('data-rownum')" and "e.target.dataset.rownum" none of them works "e.target.dataset" returns empty object => DOMStringMap {  } but the <Icon> is component which i think i need include in my question , so if you may take a look again after edit.

Comment: I see, I use onClick in the tbody to capture the click. Then in the handler is like yours setting state with proper row (I use e.target.dataset.row) then rendering the form in the table. You may try putting onClick={this._showEditor} in other places (maybe tbody) to read the event and row properly. HIH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to reveive the idx from the map function you should pass it to the function `_showEditor` so your code must be like this :

```
<Icon className="edit" onClick={this._showEditor(idx)}/>
```

and the function definition should be :

```
_showEditor = (idx) => (event) => {
   this.setState({
        editing:{
                  row:idx
                        }
                    });
        console.log(this.state.editing);
}
```

or if you don't want to use the arrow functions for some reason, just replace

```
onClick={this._showEditor(idx)}
```

with

```
onClick={this._showEditor.bind(this,idx)}
```

and its definition becomes

```
_showEditor(idx){...}
```

Comment: first solution doesnt work , the second is totally fine  thanks for that :)